# Totally rational hypergeometric evaluations

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, hypergeometric-functions

This is a followup to the question [at which rational points does the Hypergeometric function take rational values](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14897/at-which-rational-points-does-the-hypergeometric-function-take-rational-values) asked 10 years ago by
Eugene Starling, and is more a challenge than a question.

Let $F(a,b;c;z)={}_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ be the standard Gauss hypergeometric function, analytically
continued to the whole of $\mathbb C$ with a branch cut on $[1,\infty[$. For which
rational values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $z$ is the value rational ?

To make the question interesting, we must exclude some "trivial" cases.

First, none of $a$, $b$, $c-a$, or $c-b$ must be integral: indeed, otherwise there are easy
examples such as $$F(a,2;c;(c-2)/(a-1))=(a-1)(c-1)/(a-c+1)$$
or trivial examples when $a$ or $b$ is a negative integer.

Second, we must exclude the case where $F(a,b;c;z)$ is an algebraic function (which can
easily be checked using a criterion which can be found for instance in a fundamental paper
of Beukers and Heckman): indeed, if the corresponding algebraic curve has genus $0$ it
can be rationally parametrized, for instance
$$F(1/4,3/4;1/2;4x^2(1-x^2))=x/(2x^2-1)\text{ for $x>1/\sqrt{2}$}\;.$$
A third method, mentioned by Noam Elkies in a comment to the abovementioned post, is to
use CM elliptic modular curves. However, this seems to give only a finite number of rational evaluations:
I found $12$, listed in abbreviated form as $(a,b,c,z,r)$ meaning $r=F(a,b;c;z)$:

$(1/8,1/8,1/2,-2400,2/3)$, $(3/8,3/8,1/2,-2400,2/21)$, $(1/8,1/8,3/4,-25920,3/5)$,
$(5/8,5/8,3/4,-25920,3/805)$, $(1/4,1/4,3/4,-80,3/5)$, $(1/2,1/2,3/4,-80,1/5)$,
$(1/4,1/2,3/4,80/81,9/5)$, $(1/6,1/6,5/6,-3024,4/7)$, $(2/3,2/3,5/6,-3024,4/385)$,
$(1/3,1/3,5/6,-27,4/7)$, $(1/2,1/2,5/6,-4,3/5)$, $(1/3,1/3,2/3,-8,2/3)$.

Finally, there is an isolated additional example which, as Noam mentions, comes from a
Shimura curve $(1/3,2/3,5/6,27/32,8/5)$.

So just for the sake of it, does anyone have additional examples ?